# SQL: Find multiple client numbers for same person

Tags: sql, select

How can I find if a name is assigned different client number?
For example, how can I find Jude in the dataset was assigned three different client numbers? I've tried to use group by to find the duplicate client numbers.

```
ID   CLIENT_NUMBER  NAME  START_DT       END_DT
 1      1           Jude   2017-09-13    NULL
 2      2           Jude   2017-09-19    2017-09-26
 3      3           Jude   2017-09-26    null
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you running? MySQL, Sql Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc

Answer (score 2):

You could count how many distinct client_numbers each name has:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT client_name) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM
YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENT_NUMBER) > 1;
```